# Uniform, consistent error responses from ASP.Net Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing a Web API 2 application and I'm currently trying to format error resposnes in a uniform way (so that the consumer will also know what data object/structure they can inspect to get more info about the errors). This is what I've got so far:

```
{   
    "Errors":
    [
        {
            "ErrorType":5003,
            "Message":"Error summary here",
            "DeveloperAction":"Some more detail for API consumers (in some cases)",
            "HelpUrl":"link to the docs etc."
        }
    ]
}
```

This works fine for exceptions thrown by the application itself (i.e inside controllers). However, if the user requests a bad URI (and gets a 404) or uses the wrong verb (and gets a 405) etc, Web Api 2 spits out a default error message e.g.

```
{
     Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/abc'."
}
```

Is there any way of trapping these kinds of errors (404, 405 etc.) and formatting them out into the error response in the first example above?

So far I've tried:

- Custom ExceptionAttribute inherting `ExceptionFilterAttribute`
- Custom ControllerActionInvoker inherting `ApiControllerActionInvoker`
- `IExceptionHandler` (new Global Error Handling feature from Web API 2.1)

However, none of these approaches are able to catch these kinds of errors (404, 405 etc). Any ideas on how/if this can be achieved?

...or, am I going about this the wrong way? Should I only format error responses in my particular style for application/user level errors and rely on the default error responses for things like 404?

Comment: `Should I only format error responses in my particular style for application/user level errors and rely on the default error responses for things like 404?`...my opinion is yes

Comment: I'm been swaying towards this approach more and more too. Thanks both for your great answers/comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override the DelegatingHandler abstract class and intercept the response to the client. This will give you the ability to return what you want.

Here's some info on it.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Here's a poster of the Web Api pipeline that shows what can be overriden. 
http://www.asp.net/posters/web-api/asp.net-web-api-poster.pdf

Create a Handler class like this to override the response

```
public class MessageHandler1 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Process request");
        // Call the inner handler.
        var response = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        Debug.WriteLine("Process response");
        if (response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            //Create new HttpResponseMessage message
        }
        ;
        return response;
    }
}
```

In your WebApiConfig.cs class add the handler.

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageHandler1());
```

**UPDATE**
As Kiran mentions in the comments you can use the OwinMiddleware to intercept the response going back to the client. This would work for MVC and Web Api running on any host.

Here's an example of how to get the response and change it as it goes to the client.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(typeof(MyMiddleware)); 
    }
}

public class MyMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public MyMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) { }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await Next.Invoke(context);
        if(context.Response.StatusCode== 404)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            context.Response.ReasonPhrase = "Blah";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This alone would not be enough as in some cases requests would not even come into Web API due to no Web API route matches.(This problem is specific to IIS hosted scenarios). This problem could be circumvented by having a catch all route in the end of Web API routes which can send back a custom 404 error message...other possible solutions is to have an OwinMiddleware which sits earlier in the pipeline and this way you have all your logic in one single place (i haven't played with this myself but i am guessing this should work)

Comment: It will hit the DelegatingHandler for all api calls even if the route is incorrect because the HttpRoutingDispatcher gets called after the DelegatingHandlers. You are correct, that if the request is not an api request it will not hit this handler because non api calls get handled by System.Web.Mvc namespace handlers. Example: http://localhost/WebApplication1/api/invalid will hit this handler but http://localhost/WebApplication1/invalid will not hit this handler...assuming all api calls are setup to start with http://localhost/WebApplication1/api/

Comment: Just to be clear...route matching at `HttpRoutingDispatcher` only happens for SelfHost and In-Memory scenarios...

Comment: @Kiran Charla - do you have any documentation on that? My understanding is that the whole purpose of OWIN is to separate the app from the host. This means everything starting with the DelegatingHandler into the app doesn't care how its hosted. This includes the HttpRoutingDispatcher.

Comment: actually you could use your example above to verify this...create a IIS based Web API application without any MVC related stuff..now have the default api route as the template provides..i.e `api/{controller}/{id}`...now make a request like `localhost/yourwebapplicationname/nonexistingpath`...if route matching was indeed happening at `HttpRoutingDispatcher` then your delegatinghandler should have been called...but it doesn't...because route matching happened earlier than the request passed through your delegating handler...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said in my first comment. This solution is only good for api related routes. All other requests, like the one you just described, will hit the System.Web.Mvc namespace objects because in our WebApiConfig.cs class we said api requests use the route template starting with api/. That means any requests that do not start with api/ will be checked against the MVC routes.

Comment: I am not clear as to what you are trying to say here...a request like 'api/blah/10/abc/' would also not match and would never hit the handler...the point is route matching happens much earlier in IIS hosted scenarios and HttpRoutingDisparcher only does it for self host and I memory scenarios...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55630/discussion-between-dan-h-and-kiran-challa).

Comment: I read about OWIN middleware, but my ASP.net Web Api project not contain OWIN, I'm afraid of using it, and need to know will it affect any other working functionality or hosting settings? will it affect the already exists "DelegatingHandler" MessageHandlers ? or "ActionFilterAttribute" Filters?

Answer (score 2):

I have done in same way as @Dan H mentioned

```
 public class ApiGatewayHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                var objectContent = response.Content as ObjectContent;
                return await Task.FromResult(new ApiResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, VmsStatusCodes.RouteNotFound, "", objectContent == null ? null : objectContent.Value).Response());
            }
            return response;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(new ApiResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, VmsStatusCodes.UnHandledError, ex.Message, "").Response());
        }

    }
}
```

Added routing like below and now it hits the try catch for invalid url

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi",routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "NotFound", routeTemplate: "api/{*paths}", defaults: new { controller = "ApiError", action = "NotFound" });
```