# Customizing "No http resource was found that matches the request uri" message

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Is there a simple way to modify the default 404 message returned by Web API?

> No http resource was found that matches the request uri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the [DelegatingHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler(v=vs.118).aspx) abstract class.

see more here [Uniform, consistent error responses from ASP.Net Web API 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207583/uniform-consistent-error-responses-from-asp-net-web-api-2)

and here, [ASP.NET Web API Exception Handling](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/asp-net-web-api-exception-handling)

Comment: Instead of using OWIN middleware as the update in link #2 suggests?

Comment: you can go OWIN middleware, of course. My suggestion is to try both and see which one works better for you

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do that is by "DelegatingHandler"

1. First Step is to create a new class inherits from DelegatingHandler:

   ```
       public class ApiGatewayHandler : DelegatingHandler
       { 
          protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
          {
            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

           if (response!=null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
           {
               var msg = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

               //you can change the response here
               if (msg != null && msg.Contains("No HTTP resource was found"))
               {
                   return new HttpResponseMessage
                   {
                       StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
                       Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(object), new { Message = "New Message..No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI" }, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
                   };
               }
           }
           return response;

       return response;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Then Register this class in the web api Register config file

   ```
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config){
       public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
       {
           // you config and routes here                

           config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ApiGatewayHandler());

           //....
       }
   }
   ```

That is it. Same way if you need to change any other error message.